# make UIImageView fall

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I've `UIImageview` with its own position, after clicking that ( done with `tapgesture` ) I want that view to fall to ground until the position is 0. I tried making it with while loop but doesn't seem to work. any soltuions ?

```swift
    var bananaView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let centerPosition = bananaView.frame.origin.y
        while centerPosition >= 0 {
            bananaView.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y : centerPosition - 1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `CABasicAnimation`

Comment: While loops and other loops in swift happen instantly, so they aren’t great for animations. Better to use UIView.animate instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the new position (0) for it. Then you wrap the layout update inside an animation block

```
@objc func handleTap(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let centerPosition = bananaView.frame.origin.y
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { timer in
        if bananaView.frame.origin.y - bananaView.frame.height == 0 {
            timer.invalidate()
        } else {
            bananaView.frame.origin.y -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do what I asked without `animate` ? It's an assignment given at school and we haven't learnt `animate` yet

Comment: You can do it with a Timer and repeatInterval, but that would be kind of an hack solution

Comment: I copied your code, xCode returned an error to add `self` before `bananaView` I fixed that error but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: i changed it to timer.. but normally you don't want to work with frames. You should read up on anchorPoints and constraints